# Getting all the data in an xml via javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Trying to spool out all the post and also all the comment for each post from the DB using ajax/javascript.

I'm getting the actual data from the DB via ajax correctly but having issues fetching the xml nodes and displaying them in the div container.

The data being displayed are incorrect. i.e if a post has more than one comment, it displays only one and again if a post has no comment, it does not display every other post.

While trying to get all the comments for each post, i created another for loop within the first loop but got stucked specifying the correct childNode to run the loop, so i just had try it out like i've shown in the javascript below.

Just need help fixing this and i'm sure it has to do with how i'm working with the xml nodes.

**Here's the sample of the xml structure:**

```
<post>

<post_unit poster_pix="john_doe.jpg" poster_name="john doe" poster_acctype="user" post_time="12:12 pm, Jul 5 2013" post_msg="Not so cool" post_img="post_img.jpg">

<comment com_name="ben tyler" com_acctype="admin" com_time="10:12 am, Jul 6 2013" com_msg="how about now">
</comment>

<comment com_name="thelma jones" com_acctype="supervisor" com_time="02:12 pm, Jul 6 2013" com_msg="okay">
</comment>

</post_unit>


<post_unit poster_pix="tom_hay.jpg" poster_name="Tom hayden" poster_acctype="user" post_time="12:12 pm, Jul 5 2013" post_msg="it aint working" post_img="post_img.jpg">

</post_unit>

</post>
```

**Here is the the javascript:**

```
<script>

var getStatusPost = XmlHttpRequestObject();
var mTimer;



function fetchAllData() {
    getStatusPostFunc();
}   

// Checking if XMLHttpRequest object exist in user browser
function XmlHttpRequestObject(){
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else{
        document.getElementById("ajax_status").innerHTML = "Status: Unable to launch Chat Object. Consider upgrading your browser.";
}
}




// Fetch all post
function getStatusPostFunc(){
        getStatusPost.open("GET", "inc/status_post_processor.php?all_post&t=" + Math.random(), true);
        getStatusPost.onreadystatechange = statusPostReceivedHandler;
        getStatusPost.timeout = 20000; //set timeout for xmlhttp request
        getStatusPost.ontimeout = statusPostTimeoutHandler;
        getStatusPost.send(null);
}

// Handle timeout for fetching post
function statusPostTimeoutHandler(){
        getStatusPost.abort(); //abort the timedout xmlhttprequest
        setTimeout(function(){getStatusPostFunc()}, 20000);
}


// Receives response from server for all post and comment
function statusPostReceivedHandler(){

    if(getStatusPost.readyState == 4){
        if(getStatusPost.status == 200){

            var post_holder_div = document.getElementById('status_update_msg_area');
            post_holder_div.innerHTML = '';             

            var xmldoc = getStatusPost.responseXML;
            var postNode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("post_unit");
            for(i = 0; i < postNode.length; i++){

                post_holder_div.innerHTML += '<p><strong>Poster name:</strong> ' + postNode[i].getAttribute("poster_name") + '</p>';

                post_holder_div.innerHTML += '<p><strong>Post:</strong> ' + postNode[i].getAttribute("post_msg") + '</p>';

                post_holder_div.innerHTML += '<br><h3>Comments</h3><br>';

                post_holder_div.innerHTML += '<p>' + postNode[i].childNodes[0].getAttribute("com_name") + ': <em>' + postNode[i].childNodes[0].getAttribute("com_msg") + '</em></p>';

                post_holder_div.innerHTML += '<br /><hr /><br />'

            }       

        }
    }   

}

</script>
```

Would be pleased and grateful getting help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to change your XML structure to something like this ..

```
<posts>
    <post>
        <author>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <acctype>Admin</acctype>
        </author>
        <time>09/07/2013</time>
        <msg>This is a message</msg>
        <img>
            <url>post_img.jpg</url>
        </img>
        <comments>
            <comment>
                <author>
                    <name>John Smith</name>
                    <acctype>basic</acctype>
                </author>
                <time>09/07/2013</time>
                <content>comment number 1</content>
            </comment>
            <comment>
                <author>
                    <name>Jane Doe</name>
                    <acctype>basic</acctype>
                </author>
                <time>09/07/2013</time>
                <content>comment number 1</content>
            </comment>
        </comments>
    </post>
    <post>
       ......
    <post>
</posts>
```

And then you can have your JavaScript as follows ...

```
var post_holder_div = document.getElementById('status_update_msg_area');
post_holder_div.innerHTML = '';

var posts = xmlDom.getElementsByTagName("post"), domString = '';
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    var poster = posts[i].getElementsByTagName('author')[0].childNodes[0].textContent,
        message = posts[i].getElementsByTagName('msg')[0].textContent,
        time = posts[i].getElementsByTagName('time')[0].textContent,
        comments = posts[i].getElementsByTagName('comments')[0].childNodes;

    domString += '<p><strong>Poster name:</strong> ' + poster + '</p>';
    domString += '<p><strong>Post:</strong> ' + message + '</p>';

    if (comments.length) {

        domString += '<h4>Comments</h4>';

        for (var j = 0; j < comments.length; j++) {
            var commenter = comments[j].getElementsByTagName('author')[0].childNodes[0].textContent,
                comment = comments[j].getElementsByTagName('content')[0].textContent;

            domString += '<p>' + commenter + ': <em>' + comment + '</em></p>';

        }
    }

}

post_holder_div.innerHTML = domString;
```

This should give you a rough idea. With the comments you want to have them nested i.e. `<comment/>` as a subchild of `<comments/>`.  is to  as  is to

NB: Of course the JS code could be refactored and be neater but this is just help you on your way.

I hope this helps :)