# Displaying nodes from an XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following XML file. I want to display every child node of the node `comment` under the condition that the `title` node value is equal to "hey" (for example).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<database>
  <entry>
    <title>hey</title>
    <content>it works!!</content>
    <time>8/6/2013 3:05:59 PM</time>
    <comment><title>aa</title><text>bb</text><rating>2</rating></comment>
    <comment><title>yyyyy</title><text>yyyy</text><rating>0</rating></comment>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</title>
    <content>aaaaaaaaa</content>
    <time>8/6/2013 3:08:11 PM</time>
  </entry>
</database>
```

I tried doing this with some `for` loops, but it didn't always work. Is there a simple way to solve my problem using javascript?

Here is some sample code I tried using (only the first part). How should I continue from here?

```
x=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;

for (a=0;a<x.length;a++) {
    if (x.item(a).nodeType==1) {
        if(x.item(a).getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue=="<?php echo $_REQUEST["title"]; ?>") {
            for (b=0;b<3;b++) {
                document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += "<h3>"+x.item(a).getElementsByTagName("comment")[b].childNodes[0].textContent+"</h3>";
                document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += "<p>"+x.item(a).getElementsByTagName("comment")[b].childNodes[1].textContent+"</p>";
                document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += "<div>"+x.item(a).getElementsByTagName("comment")[b].childNodes[2].textContent+"</div>";
                document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += "<hr></hr>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered something similar here, hope this helps ... **[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549881/getting-all-the-data-in-an-xml-via-javascript/)**

If not let me know

**HTML**

```
<div id='comments'></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var xmlDoc = loadXMLString(xml),
    x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes,
    domStr = '',
    commentDiv = document.getElementById("comments");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].nodeType === 1){
        var commmentNode = x[i].getElementsByTagName("comment");
        for (var j = 0; j < commmentNode.length; j++){
            if ( commmentNode[j].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0].textContent === "hey") {
                domStr += "<h3>" + commmentNode[j].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0].textContent + "</h3>";
                domStr += "<p>" + commmentNode[j].getElementsByTagName('text')[0].childNodes[0].textContent + "</p>";
                domStr += "<div>" + commmentNode[j].getElementsByTagName('rating')[0].childNodes[0].textContent + "</div><hr></hr>";
                console.log(domStr);
                commentDiv.innerHTML += domStr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO**

**[UPDATE JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/akRRY/)**

Comment: Could you please help to display all the child nodes from the comment node?

Comment: will approve your answer. but could you please say me how i get the number of comment nodes in the entry node?

Comment: @PhilippBraun did it work for you? if so could accept it as your answer :)

Comment: please just have a look at my code i need it to work without jquery (code from me works just need to replace the 3;)

Comment: Tried this x.item(a).getElementsByTagName("comments").childNodes.length But didn't work.